# How does input work when exporting to Android?

Tags: unity, android, input

I know I must add Android sdk , but my question is this :

If I make a game that works with the mouse, for example a puzzle game, then I output my game to Android, do I have to rewrite it to work with the touch screen?

Answer (score 5):

With Unity, the mouse input will work like a touch input on android, automatically.

Alternatively, you can look at the [Input.touches](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) class to handle multiple touches.